# Алгоритм Брезенхэма для эллипса

Tags: алгоритм, графика

Подскажите как нарисовать **эллипс** методом Брезенхэма. Об окружности написано много где и много чего, а с эллипсом ничего не нашёл

Comment: [ИНТУИТ-овская лекция](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/993/163/lecture/4495?page=5) подойдёт?

Comment: Да, большое спасибо и за лекцию, и за сайт в общем